# How can I provide dynamic data to custom intent handler?

Tags: swift, sirikit, widgetkit

Context: I'm using a Custom Intent, called TestConfiguration, for the new iOS 14 widget I've created and I have "Dynamic Options" checked. My goal is to allow the user to edit the widget
view, based off an option selected from a list retrieved from the backend, and have the changes be reflected on the widget itself.

I have a class called IntentHandler that adheres to TestConfigurationIntentHandling. Within this delegate method

```
func provideAssetsOptionsCollection(for intent: TestConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<TestIntentItem>?, Error?) -> Void) {
```

I've tried to call the backend in this delegate methdo, but it always tells me "No options were provided for this parameter". So I dug in the documentation and saw the confirm delegate method and implemented it like so:

```
func confirm(intent: TestConfigurationIntent, completion: @escaping (TestConfigurationIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    completion(TestConfigurationIntentResponse(code: .inProgress, userActivity: nil))
    backendService.fetchData() { result in
        //format all the data
        completion(TestConfigurationIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: nil))
    }
}
```

But this didn't seem to work either since it's still giving me the same response. What am I not understanding / how can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you're testing this on a iOS 14.0 device, the target version of the Intent Handler is also set to iOS 14.0, instead of iOS 14.1.

Comment: That's super interesting ...because 14.1 is out now for the general public. Would you happen to know why this is the case? Is there a different implementation for 14.1?

Comment: @Jay: when a target OS version of an extension (14.1) is higher than the OS of the device (14.0), it will not be loaded. So in this case you end up with a working Widget combined with a non-working Intent handler.

Comment: That makes sense, I hadn't noticed that it was only available in iOS 14.0. How can I accommodate for 14.1?

Comment: @Jay: if your target OS for both the Widget and Intent Handler are set to 14.0, then it should also work in 14.1. Or 14.2, released today.

Comment: I have iOS 16 in the simulator and device and the target is 14.0 still widget is unable to load.